# how to create animation bar that rises to a certain height depending on the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Hi I need to create an animation of a barrel filling up to values and need to know how best to do it so that the client can update the value themselves an the animation will automatically know where to stop filling the barrel. Finally at the end once the top value is reached some sort of animation appears saying congrats.

eg. Barrel amounts from bottom to top are 0,10k,30k,50k,70k,80k and finally 100k

I just need an easy way to do this using html,javascript/jquery and even xml so that they can update the value daily themselves

Thanks any help would be massively appreciated

Comment: [this could also be something](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/TntE9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the progress html5 element.

If you want it to be vertical, i think only mozilla prodive a `-moz-orient` property.

But you can rotate it using `transform: rotate(-90deg);`

Comment: thanks for that - its perfect but it looks like it doesn't work on ie9 or below. Is ther a way to get it to work using modernizr perhaps?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make it work in older browers. But, you can use jquery ui, it has a progress bar component and should work everywhere. (see : http://jqueryui.com/progressbar )

Comment: There is maybe another way to force a cross browser compatibility :
https://github.com/LeaVerou/HTML5-Progress-polyfill
or 
http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/01/03/cross-browser-html5-progress-bars-in-depth/